# Probability distribution and entropy of a set of possible outcomes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, information-theory, entropy

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables and that the possible outcomes
of $(X, Y)$ are $(1, 2), (1, 3), (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (2, 3)$ and that each of these is equally
probable. Calculate $H(X), H(Y)$ and $H(X, Y)$, and hence determine whether $X$ and $Y$ are
independent.

I know $X$ and $Y$ are independent if $H(X)+ H(Y)= H(X, Y)$

I wanted to know if I have done this correctly as I am unsure with some of the probability distributions.

I get $H(X)=-\left(\dfrac{2}{7}\log_2 \left(\dfrac{2}{7}\right)+\dfrac{1}{7}\log_2 \left(\dfrac{1}{7}\right)+\dfrac{4}{7}\log_2 \left(\dfrac{4}{7}\right)\right)$ $=1.379$

$H(Y)=-\left(\dfrac{2}{7}\log_2 \left(\dfrac{1}{7}\right)+\dfrac{2}{7}\log_2 \left(\dfrac{2}{7}\right)+\dfrac{3}{7}\log_2 \left(\dfrac{3}{7}\right)\right)$ $=1.842$

and $H(X,Y) = -\dfrac{7}{7}\log_2 \left(\dfrac{1}{7}\right)=2.807$

So hence $X$ and $Y$ are not independant. Are these calculations correct for the probability distributions? I am particulary doubtful for $H(X,Y)$

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. For example, given $Y=0$, $X$ must be equal to zero.

Comment: Yes, you will see I have stated that at the end. It is not this I need help with, it is more so with the distributions.

Comment: Your computations are correct, except for the formula for the entropy of $Y$ which implies that the $Y$ probabilities are $(2/7, 2/7, 3/7)$, whereas they are $(1/7, 1/7, 2/7, 3/7)$. Interestingly the value $1.842$ corresponds to the correct distribution and not the one shown in the formula (typo?)

Comment: @Stelios : I think the formula is correct, the term $\dfrac{2}{7}\log_2 \left(\dfrac{1}{7}\right)$ accounts for two probabilities of $1/7$

Comment: @leonbloy You are right, of course.